# Immitate Windows Forms layout in Java

Tags: java, forms

I come from C# but now I must program in Java. Everything is quite similar but I have a hard time figuring layouts. In C# (and other languages that use Windows Form) you can display elements on your form by "anchoring" them to one or more edge(s) of the form, which makes it easy to predict the behavior of the form upon resize etc.

I know about GridLayout and GridBagLayout, but I'm trying to program a form where label are dynamically changing location in the form (they must move a bit like the tiles do in the 2048 game) and I can't figure how to do this with those layouts.

Is there a way to replicate the Windows Form behavior in Java? I would be looking for something like this :

```
label.setLocation(x, y);
```

Comment: You'll find that learning a new technology/framework/etc. is a lot easier if you don't try to make it fit the technology/framework/etc. you already know.  Walk through the guides and tutorials for the tools you're using, not for the tools you've used in the past.

Comment: does this require animation? How do you mean dynamic? Dynamic at load time?

Comment: Dynamic meaning I would like some label to be displayed and others to be discarded while the program is running. And yes I was planning on making them move so it requires animation.

Comment: I'm begining to think it would be much easier to simply draw the content of the labels I want to show and repaint the form periodically so it gives a frame by frame animation, but then I lose the possibility of listening for events